Extract abstract from PubMed using BioPython and writing to CSV
I am quite new to Python, and would like to extract abstracts from pubmed using the bio entrez package. I can get abstract based on a given ID list and write into csv.
My code is:
papers = fetch_details(chunk)
  for i, paper in enumerate (papers['PubmedArticle']):
    title_list.append(paper['MedlineCitation']['Article']['ArticleTitle'])
    try:
      abstract_list.append(paper['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Abstract']['AbstractText'])
    except:
      abstract_list.append('No Abstract')

However, if the abstracts contain more than one paragraphs, such as "Purpose/Objective, Method, Results, Conclusion", The abstract looks like below:
[StringElement('Bruton tyrosine kinase (BTK) is a key component of B-cell receptor signalling, critical for cell proliferation. Acalabrutinib, a selective, covalent BTK inhibitor, recently received an accelerated approval in relapsed/refractory mantle cell lymphoma. This analysis characterized the population pharmacokinetics (PK) of acalabrutinib and its metabolite ACP-5862.', attributes={'Label': 'INTRODUCTION'}), StringElement('Data were obtained from six phase I/II trials in adult patients with B-cell malignancy and seven phase I trials in healthy volunteers. Pooled concentration-time data, at dose levels ranging from 15 to 400\xa0mg, were analysed using non-linear mixed-effects modelling. Base model parameters were scaled with body weight and normalized to 70\xa0kg (fixed exponents: 0.75 and 1 for clearance and volumes, respectively). A full covariate approach was used to evaluate any relevant effects of dose, health group/disease status, hepatic and renal impairment, use of acid-reducing agents, race and sex.', attributes={'Label': 'METHODS'}), StringElement('A total of 11,196 acalabrutinib and 1068 ACP-5862 concentration-time samples were available. The PK of both analytes were well described using two-compartment disposition models. Acalabrutinib absorption was characterized using sequential zero- and first-order constants and a lag time. Apparent clearance (CL/F) of acalabrutinib was 169 L/h (95% CI 159-175). Relative to the 100\xa0mg dose group, the 15 and 400\xa0mg dose groups showed a 1.44-fold higher and 0.77-fold lower CL/F, respectively. The clearance for ACP-5862 was 21.9 L/h (95% CI
19.5-24.0). The fraction metabolized was fixed to 0.4. The central and peripheral volumes of distribution were 33.1 L (95% CI 24.4-41.0) and 226 L (95% CI 149-305) for acalabrutinib, and 38.5\xa0L (95% CI
31.6-49.2) and 38.4 L (95% CI 32.3-47.9) for ACP-5862. None of the investigated covariates led to clinically meaningful changes in exposure.', attributes={'Label': 'RESULTS'}), StringElement('The PK of acalabrutinib and its metabolite ACP-5862 were adequately characterized. Acalabrutinib CL/F decreased with increasing dose, but the trend was small over the 75-250\xa0mg range. No dose adjustment was necessary for intrinsic or extrinsic covariates.', attributes={'Label': 'CONCLUSION'})]

It formatted as :  [StringElement('',attributes={'Label':'INTRODUCTION'})]
How could I get the text without the structure format?
